# Blank database values show as 0, not blank

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, servicenow

I use Crystal Reports 2016 to report on data in ServiceNOW (integration through ODBC). I am working on a report that will identify when fields are not filled out in a specific form. I'm running into an issue identifying the difference between when a field is not filled out (blank entry in database, not null) and when that field is filled out with a 0.

CR16 appears to always interpret a blank entry as 0, to the point where it can be summed and is registering as a number, not a string. I've tried using isnull({table.field}) but since the field entry is blank, not null, that doesn't work. I also can compare that blank entry to an entry that is 0 and CR16 returns it as the same, despite confirmation that the entries are different in the SNOW database.

I've looked around on Google quite a bit, but people tend to use blank and null interchangeably, and in this case SNOW's specifically showing a blank in that cell vs. a null or a 0 value.

I'm assuming this is a setting, like the "NULLs as default values" settings in Report Options (which do nothing for this, by the way). Is anyone aware of a technique to be able to return a blank instead of a value for this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by `blank entry`?

Comment: I work with NULL values in CR2016 every day, so the problem is somewhere in your setup.  In the report where this is happening try clicking File > Report Options and see if the check box for "Convert Database NULL Values to Default" is checked.  You may also want to check how the report is connecting to the database.  If it uses a stored procedure, check that stored procedure to see if it might be replacing NULL values with a zero.

Comment: Like I said, this isn't null entries, it's blanks - that is, if I export to Excel, a COUNT would find an entry in the blank entry, and wouldn't find one in a NULL. 

I did try the Convert values to Default entry and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check the database connection to see if there might be a stored procedure that is substituting values conditionally?  By "blank" do you mean "empty string"?

Comment: It does appear to be an empty string or empty set - when I export the record from ServiceNOW as a CSV file and look at the blank value in Notepad++, it shows as ""...which doesn't make sense, because the value is a numerical value so it can't be a string.

Comment: Just because they are empty string values in SNOW, doesn't mean they are in the database or crystal reports though.  SNOW saves values to a database, then CR reports on values from that database.  The way the data is stored in the database by SNOW or the way the data is queried and sent to CR could be transforming the values to numbers.  It would be helpful if you could provide as much detail as possible about the database your report uses.  How is it integrated through ODBC?

Comment: I don't have that information, unfortunately. Rather, I don't know where to look to answer your question - I'm just an analyst. If you tell me what to check, I can do that, but that's about it. Sorry for the lack of knowledge on my part.